# Are writes to a MutableByteArray atomic?

Tags: arrays, haskell, ghc

I'm using the [`primitive` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.5.2.1/docs/Data-Primitive-ByteArray.html) and I would like to make sure writes (in particular of types wider than a word) from one thread cannot be seen as garbage from another. This is sometimes referred to as "tearing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is undefined behavior, and in any case multi-word writes are not atomic, as demonstrated by this quick-and-dirty program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnboxedTuples #-}
module Main where
import Data.Primitive.Types
import Data.Primitive.ByteArray
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import GHC.Prim
main = do
    arr <- newByteArray 16  -- on 64-bit, this is enough for two Ints (8 each)
    inp <- newTVarIO (0::Int)
    o1 <- newEmptyTMVarIO
    o2 <- newEmptyTMVarIO
    let writer last = do
            val <- atomically $ do
                    x <- readTVar inp
                    x <$ check (x > last)
            let v' = (val,val+1)
            writeByteArray arr 0 v'
            atomically $ putTMVar o1 ()
            writer val
        reader last = do
            val <- atomically $ do
                    x <- readTVar inp
                    x <$ check (x > last)
            rVal <- readByteArray arr 0 :: IO (Int,Int)
            let v1 = (val,val+1)
                v0 = (val-1,val)
            when (not $ rVal `elem` [v0,v1,(0,0)]) $ error $ show (val, "got:", rVal)
            atomically $ putTMVar o2 ()
            reader val
    let control :: Int -> IO ()
        control !n = do
            atomically $ writeTVar inp n
            mapM_ (atomically . takeTMVar) [o1,o2]
            when (n<100000) $ control (n+1)
    forkIO $ writer 0
    forkIO $ reader 0
    control 1
    print "done!"

instance Prim (Int,Int) where
    sizeOf# _ = 2# *# (sizeOf# (undefined :: Int))
    alignment# _ = alignment# ( undefined :: Int)
    readByteArray# arr n s = case readByteArray# arr (2# *# n) s of
        (#s',i1 #) -> case readByteArray# arr ((2# *# n) +# 1#) s of
          (#s'2,i2 #) -> (#s'2,(i1,i2)#)
    writeByteArray# arr n (i1,i2) s = case writeByteArray# arr (2# *# n) i1 s of
          s' -> writeByteArray# arr ((2# *# n) +# 1#) i2 s'
```

building this program with ghc-7.6.3, `-O2 -threaded -rtsopts`, in 7 executions with `-N3` I got the following outcomes:

```
foo: (4,"got:",(3,5))
foo: (59037,"got:",(59036,59038))
foo: "done!"
foo: (92936,"got:",(92936,92936))
foo: (399,"got:",(398,400))
foo: (7196,"got:",(7195,7197))
foo: (11950,"got:",(11950,11950))
```

reads/writes of a single machine word are probably atomic so long as the memory model of the CPU architecture makes that guarantee.

One objection to this demo is that the Prim instance for `(Int,Int)` is bogus.  Which it sort-of is.  However, given the available primitives, I don't see how to implement anything better for multi-word types.

You'll need to use some other synchronization method to ensure that multi-word writes are atomic.  One simple approach is to keep your array in an `MVar`.  Or maybe my [kickchan](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/kickchan) package would help (at least inspirationally, if it doesn't address your use case).

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting the work into testing that out! My idea was to maybe shortcut some more complex coordination between a single reader and writer pair when a write has already happened. If I end up using `MutableByteArray`s after all my approach will probably be to have a sibling `MutableByteArray` to handle coordination either with a CAS (provided by `atomic-primops`) or some other mutual exclusion scheme like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm.

Comment: @jberryman: yes, either of those would give finer-grained locking than a single `MVar`.  I'm a bit unsure of the performance of `atomic-primops`; I think that it's slower than it should be given what's necessary to make some of the operations atomic (again, due to GHC/Haskell's lack of a memory model).